# How the optical fibre pH microsensors work?

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, ph, fluorescence, sensor

Just browsed through the chemical sensor products of the company, called PreSens (https://www.presens.de/products/ph/sensors) in order to look for a precise method to measure pH change in a physiological solution (Dulbecco's Phosphate Buffer Saline 1M).

I just would like to know how the "Sensor Spot" and "Needle type" optical sensors work exactly. According to the brochure on the aforementioned page, the Sensor Spots seem to based on fluorescence quenching: basically a quencher (I believe the hydrogen ions or the hydronium ions? I'm not sure) reduce the detected fluorescence intensity of the fluorophore (some pH dependent dye incorporated into a membrane "spot").

I would like to know more about this mechanism, I leafed through numerous reviews, but I have not be able to find any detailed information about pH detection based on fluorescence quenching. What is the quencher here? Could you tell me what is the mechanism in this particular case?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you make a bit clearer what your actual question is? The flourescence changes (is diminished, "quenched") in the presence of H+, that's it. E.g. green light is coupled into the fiber, some red fluorescence comes back out, depending on pH. Are you asking for the chemistry of the dye?

Comment: No, I won't need such detailed chemistry, just how the pH change detected in this case by the sensor (the matrix intercalated with the dye)? The detection method I would like to know. Do they detect the back-propogated fluorescence and its change in wavelenght or what?

Comment: The link you posted clearly mentions the name of the principle involved in such pH measurements. There is no electrochemistry. It is called dual lifetime referencing (DLR) method. https://bmcbiotechnol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1472-6750-12-11

Comment: Oh, I missed that description on the bottom of the page. Thanks for letting me know.